# Parsing JSON Data in iOS application Return Null Array

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, json

I am parsing JSON data from URL. The URL has data but array returns null in code here is the code which i am using for parsing.

```
      tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"http://ec2-54-84-162-129.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hotelcms/getActivityHotel.php?ActivityDate=Sunday March 15th&ActivityNameID=1"]];

 NSLog(@"Temp Array is %@",tempArray);
```

Here is the DataController Class

```
    @interface DataController : NSObject {

     }
    + (id)staticVersion;
    - (NSMutableArray *) startParsing:(NSString *)theURLString;
    @end

   @implementation DataController

   DataController *theInstance;
  + (id)staticVersion                                                                         


  {

    if(!theInstance){
    theInstance = [[DataController alloc] init];
    }
  return theInstance;
  }


 - (NSMutableArray *) startParsing:(NSString *)theURLString {

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theURLString]];
  NSString *fileContent= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
  SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  
  NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:fileContent error:nil];  
NSArray *items = (NSArray *) data ;  
return items;
}
 @end
```

Comment: Why are you calling [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", theString]]? That's utterly, utterly pointless.

Comment: The data you are parsing is not in proper JSON Format. For it you need to use xml parsing

Answer (score 1):

The response from that URL is not a valid JSON object. See if you can remove the erroneous "Sunday March 15th" from the start of the response.

Comment: It's amazing how helpless people are with the slightest problem. He should have figured that out himself within 10 seconds.